# metabase public link is not working. Website is not reachable

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, dashboard, metabase

i finished my metabase dashboard and wanted to share it via the public link. But when using the public link i get an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error. "Website is not reachable. The answer of "IP" took too long.

Metabase is running on a EC2 machine (Ubuntu). Everything is working fine just the public link makes trouble.

Any idea?

Comment: Start with the basics:
1.)  Are you sure your instane ha a public IP and/or Elasti IP?
2.)  Have you properly set up the security group to allow access for ports 80 and/or 443 (or others, if required by your app)?
3.)  Are you sure your app is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem. The public link that was generated by metabase was not correct. I had to switch the public ip that was generated with the public ip of my EC2 Instance. Its a little bit strange that i had to do this manually because metabase is running on that ec2 instance. But i had a few reboots and restarts in the past, so maybe something happened there.